# Get the LIST of last inserted id(s) after INSERT INTO in the same mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a MySQL function that get the list of last inserted id(s) (not only the last) after the following SQL instruction:

```
insert into my_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from my_table
where id IN (1,2,3)
```

More clearly, I suppose to have this table (my_table):

```
id | c1 | c2
-------------
1  | a  | b  
2  | a  | c
3  | b  | c
4  | .. | ..
.. | .. | ..
```

New values are copied after the INSERT INTO statement and the table now appear as follows:

```
id | c1 | c2
-------------
1  | a  | b  
2  | a  | c
3  | b  | c
4  | .. | ..
.. | .. | ..
.. | .. | ..
33 | a  | b
34 | a  | c
35 | b  | c
```

This function should return the following list: 33,34,35

A provisional solution that I thought was to get the last inserted id and after create "manually" a list 33,34,35 basing from the number of rows that are copied.

But I don't know if exists a SQL native function that do this!

Comment: Why dont you get the last id after every insert and put these id's in an list? You can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` for the last inserted id.

Comment: Thank you... This might be an alternative solution!

Comment: actually what @LuudvanKeulen suggested you is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this simple query:

```
select id
from my_table
where id >= LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> With no argument, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`
>   (64-bit) value representing the **first** automatically generated
>   value successfully inserted for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as a result
>   of the most recently executed `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I always find your answers outstanding, salute to you for helping us through your huge contribution. +1 it's always really great.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you!

Comment: But what if another client inserts rows between when you issue your ``INSERT`` and this ``SELECT`` statement? It seems those ``id``s will be selected as well, which is probably not what you want if you want just the ``id``s inserted by your client. Even though each client's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is unaffected by the other, won't the `>=` will cause you to possibly select too many records?

Comment: @kmoser . . . `LASt_INSERT_ID()` is connection-based, so queries on other connections should not affect the value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand, but consider this scenario: Connection "A" and connection "B" both do an `INSERT`. They both then call `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, which returns, say, 52 for connection "A", and 53 for connection "B". If Connection "A" then issues a `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id >= LAST_INSERT_ID()`, that will include both record ID 52 (from connection "A") *and* 53 (from connection "B"). So the issue here is the `WHERE` clause, which will include IDs other than those generated by connection "A". Do you have any suggestions for getting around this?

Comment: @kmoser . . . You might want to use transactions to ensure that you get exactly the ids you want.  You can use `=` safely if your inserts are only one at a time.